# how to get value of "p" from the initial JSON output

Tags: javascript, json

I have continuous JSON output from a server-side.

```
{"first":"XXXABC1","second":{"t":35,"p":800}}

{"first":"XXXXABC2","second":{"t":35,"p":1000}}

{"first":"XXXXABC2","second":{"t":35,"p":1000}}
```

I want to record and fix the value of p using the beginning JSON data at 800 or any number shown. Is there any way to do it? Sorry for the confusion earlier

can i just add this code at the bottom?

```
   document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = message.second.p[0];
```

```
...
 function doSend()
  {

    var jsonGetData = {"command": 1, "second":["p","t"]};
    var jsonGetDataAll = {"command": 2};                                    

    {
      console.log("SENT: " + JSON.stringify(jsonGetData));
      websocket.send(JSON.stringify(jsonGetData));
    }
}

function onMessage(evt)
  {
    var message = JSON.parse(evt.data);

    console.log('>RESPONSE: ' +evt.data);
    document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = message.second.t;
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = message.second.p;
  }
```

Comment: are you getting the json array or json object

Comment: getting the first value of 'p' and printing it to html
so should display '800'

Comment: I don't understand...whats the problem that you're having ?

Comment: I can get this JSON data:

{"first":"XXXABC1","second":{"t":35,"p":800}}
{"first":"XXXXABC2","second":{"t":35,"p":1011}}
{"first":"XXXXABC2","second":{"t":35,"p":1021}}
{"first":"XXXXABC2","second":{"t":35,"p":1030}}
{"first":"XXXXABC2","second":{"t":35,"p":1020}}
{"first":"XXXXABC2","second":{"t":35,"p":1010}}

however, only the latest will be shown on the sample webpage for example
p = 1010 
I want to create a p(initial) = using the initial p above. I cannot just let p=800 because the starting p might be different.

Comment: i have updated my answer. please let me know

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, please try the following:

```
//For JSON Object from server
var jsonObject = {
    "first": "XXXABC1",
    "second": {
        "t": 35,
        "p": 800
    }
};
let expected_value = '';
if (jsonObject.second.p != null && jsonObject.second.p != undefined && isFinite(jsonObject.second.p)) {
    expected_value = jsonObject.second.p;
}
console.log(expected_value);


//For JSON Array from server
var jsonArray = [
    {
        "first": "XXXABC1",
        "second": {
            "t": 35,
            "p": 800
        }
    },
    {
        "first": "XXXXABC2",
        "second": {
            "t": 35,
            "p": 1000
        }
    },
    {
        "first": "XXXXABC2",
        "second": {
            "t": 35,
            "p": 1200
        }
    },
];
let expected_value = '';
if (jsonArray.length > 0) {
    let jsonObject = jsonArray[0];
    if (jsonObject.second.p != null && jsonObject.second.p != undefined && isFinite(jsonObject.second.p)) {
        expected_value = jsonObject.second.p;
    }
}
console.log(expected_value);
```

Comment: hi Ratan, i wanted to get the value of p from the first JSON output printed on html as a fixed value not the value of 'first'..thanks

Comment: hi ratan, thanks but the jsonobject is not defined by me, its generated depending on a sensor output so i would not have any value for p for jsonObject at the start

Comment: when you get the sensor response you just assign the jsonObject. Initially, you define jsonObject = new Object();

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the first item of JSON array, then use array index:

```
function onMessage(evt)
{
    var message = JSON.parse(evt.data);

    console.log('>RESPONSE: ' +evt.data);
    if(evt.data.length && evt.data.length > 0){
        document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = message[0].t;
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = message[0].p;
    }        
}
```